Color of disabled buttons in MUI
We are currently using a customized version of MUI. I noticed that with some elements such as the buttons, transparency is being used for disabled states instead of assigning solid colors.
Is there a reason for this?
I remember an old co-worker who was partially visually impaired saying that using transparent colors goes against accessibility, but how I understand it, MUI does this to accommodate accessibility - ie, make sure the disabled buttons are still readable in dark mode.
Can someone please enlighten me?

It's worth noting that WCAG explicitly excludes requirements to preserve colour contrast for disabled elements (what they call "inactive user interface components"). That doesn't mean they're not an accessibility issue, but rather that the accessibility issue is typical of the control. Often the best thing to do is to redesign the UI to lean less heavily on disabled controls. See this earlier question for more discussion.

You're correct that Material-UI (MUI) uses transparency for disabled states in part to ensure that these elements remain visible and legible across different themes, like dark and light modes. By adjusting the opacity rather than using a completely different color, MUI maintains the visual hierarchy and context of the disabled element within the UI while ensuring it isn't too prominent.
However, your former co-worker's concern about transparency and accessibility is also valid. Transparency can sometimes reduce the contrast between the text and the background, making it difficult for users with visual impairments to distinguish between enabled and disabled states.
To balance this, it's essential to test the contrast ratios to ensure that the disabled state still meets accessibility guidelines. According to the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG), text (including text in disabled states) should have a contrast ratio of at least 4.5:1 against its background.
In summary:

MUI uses transparency to ensure consistency across different themes, like dark and light modes.
Accessibility concerns should be addressed by ensuring that even with transparency, the disabled state has sufficient contrast according to WCAG standards.


The transparency is used so the background color is darkened by the darkness of the inactive element. Meaning a grey of 38% will darken the background color by that much.
However, you can always use contrast checker tools to see if the user interface is actually accessible.
